# Limit of sequence with rational terms

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, polynomials

Let $p(x):=a_nx^n+...+a_0$ and $q(x):=b_mx^m+...+b_0$ be two polynomial functions on $\Bbb R$ such that $a_n\neq0\neq b_m$.

Show that:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right)=0,\text{if}\;m\gt n$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right)=\frac{a_n}{b_n},\text{if}\;m=n$$
I have the knowledge of the limit theorems up to Cauchy's theorems. I cannot figure out just where I should start from.
Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Factor by the dominant monomial in the numerator and denominator.

Comment: I guess you mean the limit as $x\to\infty$ for $m$ and $n$ fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you want the $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$. So, consider de case $n=2 , m=3$ as follows:

$p(x)=a_1x^2+a_2x+a_3$ , $q(x)=b_1x^3+b_2x^2+b_3x+b_4$

Evaluating the limit: $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^2(a_1+\frac{a_2}{x}+\frac{a_3}{x^2})}{x^3(b_1+\frac{b_2}{x}+\frac{b_3}{x^2}+\frac{b_4}{x^3})}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{a_1+\frac{a_2}{x}+\frac{a_3}{x^2}}{x(b_1+\frac{b_2}{x}+\frac{b_3}{x^2}+\frac{b_4}{x^3})}=0$$

You can think similarly when $n=m$. You factor $x^n$ and you get $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ in the limit as $x\to \infty$.

I guess now you can do de general case by yourself using the same argument.